# How to switch <td> content with another <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, switch-statement, html-table

So the thing goes as following: I'm a begginer programmer (so far i know HTML, CSS some JavaScript and some C++) and we have a school project to create a chessboard with figures on them but I want to go a step further and be able to move the figures.

So far I've used the prompt function to get the coordinates and move them around but that feels far too much stone-agish. Now what I wish to accomplish is to be able to click on a , copy its content into a variable and upon clicking on another  replace its content with the one stored in the variable. (I'll deal with the rules later..)

Each  has its unique id and I have used element.firstChild.nodeValue to acquire the  content.. Any suggestions on how to do this in JavaScript without using jQuery (if it can't be done in JavaScript then by all means do it in some other language.. it's about time I start learning them anyway.. :P)

Comment: have you tried something along the lines of `element1.firstChild.nodeValue = element2.firstChild.nodeValue;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each `<td>` has a unique id, what about:

```
var lastStoredValue = "", lastClicked = ""; // = "" is important in that case
var t1 = document.getElementById("t1");     // td with id="t1"
var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");     // td with id="t2"

t1.onclick = function() {
  if (lastClicked !== "t1" && lastStoredValue.trim())
    t1.innerHTML = lastStoredValue; // replace its content with the one stored in the variable
  if (!lastStoredValue.match(new RegExp(t1.innerHTML)))
    lastStoredValue= t1.innerHTML;  // copy its content into a variable
  lastClicked = "t1";
}

t2.onclick = function() {
  if (lastClicked !== "t2" && lastStoredValue.trim())
    t2.innerHTML = lastStoredValue; // replace its content with the one stored in the variable
  if (!lastStoredValue.match(new RegExp(t2.innerHTML)))
    lastStoredValue= t2.innerHTML;  // copy its content into a variable
  lastClicked = "t2";
}
```

This gets what is stored into one `td` and puts it into a variable; then stores what is in the variable into another `td` when click on that td.